# validate_on_update prevents deletion of a specified document

Tags: couchdb

I have a simple `validate_on_update` function:

```
if (!newDoc.type) {
    throw({forbidden: "All documents must have a type specified"});
}
```

If I do

```
curl -X DELETE $HOST/$DB/$DOC?rev=$REV
```

I get back

> {"error":"forbidden","reason":"All documents must have a type specified"}

This happens even if I do

```
rev=$REV&type=type
```

Or if I do

```
-d'{"type":"type"}'
```

with curl

How can I bypass validation for deletion of documents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CouchDB internals only know reads and updates. An update can be the creation of the doc, an edit of a doc, or the deletion of the doc. Update funs can’t be circumvented for any type. To solve this, use

```js
if(!newDoc.type && !newDoc._deleted) {
    throw({forbidden: "All documents must have a type specified"});
}
```

Comment: Is this something special?  Or do you mean `newDoc._deleted` (and I would send this property)?

Comment: Ah sorry for not being explicit here. If you `DELETE` a doc, CouchDB will send the doc with the `_deleted` flag as `newDoc` to the validation function.

Comment: You can *also* PUT or POST your doc, setting the `_delete` property yourself. It will have the same effect as a `DELETE`, which might help to explain the whole story :)